# Why is Munich safer than other cities in Germany?

Tags: safety, munich

According to the [Global Resident Index 2024](https://globalresidenceindex.com/hnwi-index/safety-index/), Munich has a high safety index with a score of 0.84. The other two German cities listed were Berlin (0.79) and Frankfurt (0.78), which are well behind according to world standards.

So, why is Munich so safe?

Comment: This is a silly list. All cities in Germany are "very safe" by any reasonable standard.  I've been to many cities on this  list and the only places I started to worry are in the "below 0.4" range.

Comment: Monaco is Number four, well before Munich (0.94 vs. 0.84). When I visited Monaco with a school group in autumn, we had hardly left the train station and were just crossing the first street when one of the students almost got run over by a motorbike. Sure, the pedestrian light had turned red, it was the student's fault - but still I'm pretty sure, in Munich a cyclist would have honked, sweared, whatnot, but not almost run over a student. Monaco is the safer city? Didn't feel like that to me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a false premise and therefore not relevant to travellers.

Comment: That list is great humour though.  Amsterdam is the 3rd most dangerous city in the world when it comes to natural disasters! :-D

Answer (score 6):

I dispute the premise of the question. First, since you're comparing to "European standards", it's worth noting that many of the entries above Munich are not European cities: several being outside Europe (Abu Dhabi, Hong Kong, Wuxi, Tokyo) and several being not cities* (Douglas, Vaduz, Andorra la Vella, Saint Helier)

> The other two German cities listed were Berlin (0.79) and Frankfurt (0.78), which are well behind according to European standards.

It's not clear to me why you believe 0.78 is "well behind according to European standards". Lots of major European cities appear below Frankfurt (London, Dublin, Milan, Stockholm, Amsterdam, Paris, Brussels... the list goes on).

It's also worth looking at where the difference comes from between Munich, Berlin, and Frankfurt. I haven't done a deep dive into the full analysis because frankly it seems like a waste of time given what can be seen immediately. Of the contributing factors that website displays in the main table, the only one where Munich does better than the other German cities is the "Numbeo index", which they describe as:

> safety indexed per city compiled by Numbeo.com is based on its online survey.

This hardly sounds like a reliable way to compare safety between cities. According to wikipedia, Numbeo has at various times considered Lund the most dangerous city in the world, and Bradford and Coventry to be the two most dangerous cities in Europe.

*the definition of a city varies from place-to-place and I don't know for a fact that these aren't officially "cities", but I'm applying the everyday/colloquial usage to broadly mean a "large settlement": none of the places I mentioned have population of even 50k people. For context, even the larger among them have populations comparable to Buxtehude, a town near Hamburg which many Germans believe is fictional.